# Function definitions in a header that many interdependent things depend on?

Tags: c++, function, header

Somewhat related to [an earlier question of mine, courtesy of being part of the some project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469843/what-kind-of-pure-virtual-functions-should-a-graphics-api-abstraction-class-co?noredirect=1#comment85947762_49469843) - How horrible is it to have function definitions *(not just declarations)* in a header-only library that contains an abstract class *(class full of pure virtual functions)* that is meant to be implemented in dyamically linked libraries loaded at runtime?

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Global.hpp"

DEFINE_CLASS(Texture)
class Texture
{
public:
    virtual ~Texture() = 0;
    virtual uint16_t getWidth() = 0;
    virtual uint16_t getHeight() = 0;
    enum textureType
    {
        texture_diffuse,
        texture_specular,
        texture_normal,
        texture_height,
    };
    virtual const textureType& getTextureType() const = 0;
    static const char* stringizeTextureType(textureType type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
        case texture_diffuse:
        {
            return "texture_diffuse";
            break;
        }
        case texture_specular:
        {
            return "texture_specular";
            break;
        }
        case texture_normal:
        {
            return "texture_normal";
            break;
        }
        case texture_height:
        {
            return "texture_height";
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            return "invalid_texture_type";
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    const char* typeToString()
    {
        return stringizeTextureType(getTextureType());
    }
};
```

As I said earlier, this is an abstract class, part of a header-only library - this header will be included in various backends of a renderer engine abstraction, but it will be also included in the engine library that will invoke said backends *(after loading them in runtime, that is)*.

Given that two sorta-interdependent libraries will include this header in their source code, will this cause errors? Should I take steps to force the inlining of said functions? Should I just omit these functions altogether? Or is everything going to be fine and there's nothing wrong with my code?

Comment: Functions defined inline in a class are implicitly `inline` and will only have one definition. And if by "libraries" you mean DLLs then those aren't linked the same way as static libraries and should still work fine.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I do mean DLLs, therefore, if what you are saying is correctly, it should work fine just fine. Two DLLs, in fact: one linked dynamically (or possibly statically) to the executable, the other loaded at runtime via dlopen.